# rails g migrate with postgres prefixes commands with schema name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.5

Haven't worked with postgres in a while and I'm running into this issue on an existing project I've just started working with.

When I run `rails g migrate`, the command completes successfully; however, it generates a boatload of diffs on `db/structure.sql`.  The differences are that the revised file explicitly prefixes every command with the postgres public schema.

For example, I get many diffs like this:

`-CREATE TABLE customer (
+CREATE TABLE public.customer (`

How can I suppress this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks to be caused by the a security patch in at least Postgresql 9.4.17 [release from the 1st March](https://bucardo.org/postgres_all_versions.html#version_9.4.17) (other versions may also be affected), which changed the behaviour of `search_path` when using `$ pg_dump`.

You could try either downgrading to the previous patch version (e.g. `9.4.16`), which preserves the previous behaviour, or take the plunge and update your schema using this new version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nick!  The problem may be related to the patch you mention, but I don't think it's the full story.  The `structure.sql` diff contains a line that reads `--- Dumped from database version 9.5.10`.  So it seems like the last person to commit was on version 9.5.10, and I'm on 9.5.12.

Comment: This affects 9.6.8 as well. Thanks to Nick for clearing that out.